# Обособлять ли "да и"?

Tags: запятые

***В отличие от Парижа, Вены да и любого городка в Европе, где в кафе можно почитать газету, в Нью-Йорке таких кафе не было.***

Как я понимаю, в данном случае "да и" употреблен как усилительный союз, который не обособляется.

Возможно ли двоякое трактование употребления следующего предложения, то есть можно ли оборот с "да и" обособить как присоединительную конструкцию?

***В отличие от Парижа и Вены, да и любого городка в Европе, где в кафе можно почитать газету, в Нью-Йорке таких кафе не было.***

Comment: *употреблен как усилительный союз, который не обособляется.* - союз, который не обособляется? М-да...

Answer (score 1):

***В отличие от Парижа, Вены да и любого городка в Европе, где в кафе можно почитать газету, в Нью-Йорке таких кафе не было.***

Я полагаю, что союз ДА И имеет здесь **только соединительное** значение, так как придаточное предложение относится ко всему однородному ряду.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151

Пунктуация при союзе «да и» зависит от его значения и синтаксической функции. Не ставится запятая перед союзом «да и», имеющим **соединительное значение**...

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуация здесь такая, как с обычным "и" - то есть оба варианта правильные.

Ещё пример:

Персики, груши да и сливы - это всё фрукты.

Но:

Персики и груши, да и сливы - это всё фрукты.

Comment: всех никто не видит. )))   А баллов у вас достаточно, чтобы задавать подобные вопросы там, где положено.

Comment: Я вижу, что вас пора за флуд в бан отправлять. Делать модератору больше нечего, как только смотреть каждый раз, кто кого в репу поцеловал.